# Can I use shortcodes in mail body

Tags: shortcode, wp-mail

Can I put any type of custom shortcode for some content in mail body?

**eg:**

```
$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "Test Email";

$packages = do_shortcode('[test id="0000"]');

$message = $packages;

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortcode generation should output a string, so that should in theory be possible if you know and trust the shortcode's output.

But many shortcodes are generated with the front-end in mind and within the *loop* context, so the *mail* context might not always work though, if they depend on conditional checks like `is_single()`.

There is the `shortcode_exists()` function to make sure the shortcode exists.

It's also possible to use the shortcode's callback directly, instead of having to run the complicated parsing of `do_shortcode()`.

You might also add some validations regarding the shortcode's output, before mailing it. Like do you want allow sending an empty string?

You should also hook your mailing code, after the shortcode has been added within the `init` action.

Note that WordPress uses the `wp_mail()` wrapper that plugins can hook into.